# How to hide SharePoint and Office 365 buttons from the ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I actually have a requirement to hide the SharePoint or Office 365 buttons from the ribbon. Please see below.

[image]
Is it possible to hide them at master page level since I have it applied already. If not, I would like to change the URL when clicked on SharePoint in the ribbon.

If anyone knows, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the master page and add the following CSS, you can hide both words. This will only impact pages using the master page, so it will not impact "modern UI" pages.

```
<style>
    .o365cs-nav-brandingText { display:none !important; }
</style>
```

While you can't change the link using CSS, you can with JavaScript or jQuery.

- The Office 365 link has an ID:  O365_MainLink_Logo
- The SharePoint link does not have an ID, but could be selected as an  tag with this attribute: aria-label="Go to SharePoint".

Answer (score 1):

Add script file to your master page with below code. To hide Office 365 & SharePoint buttons from the ribbon.

```
<style>
     .o365cs-rsp-tn-hideIfAffordanceOn {display: none;}
</style>
```

[image]